# Access mobile phone messages using Python

Tags: android, python, sms

I want to read the contents of my text messages Eg : The way certain apps display the One Time Passwords (OTPs) on receiving texts, I have a use case somewhat similar to that. How can I accomplish this? Would it be possible to build this using Python? I'm trying to build a phone app/widget which would require information from my mobile phone texts